# Radio button click event not firing for the first time in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Radio button click event not firing for the first time,but firing on second click in firefox, but it works well in IE, Chrome:

```
if ($("#div-1").children().length == 1 && $("#div-1").find(':radio').length >= 1) {

    $("#done-button").hide();

    $("#div-1").find(':radio').on("click", function () {

        console.log("clicked");

        $("#done-button").click();

    });

}
```

Comment: can u share the Dom??

Comment: Can you share a plunker?

Comment: Listen to the `change` event instead of the `click`.

Comment: i can see the console output clicked..but click event on #done button not fired..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Radio Button Onclick Event Requires Two Clicks to Fire/Execute on Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410245/radio-button-onclick-event-requires-two-clicks-to-fire-execute-on-firefox)

Comment: Please show the HTML too. @BlackSheep I recommend fixing it for click. Not sure what browsers need a blur for change but some do.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
$('input:radio') 

// or $("input[type='radio']")
```

Suggestion from jQuery [docs](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)

> It is recommended to precede `:radio` with a tag name or some other
>   selector; otherwise, the universal selector ("*") is implied. In other
>   words, the bare $( ":radio" ) is equivalent to $( " *:radio" ), so $(
>   "input:radio" ) should be used instead

Comment: This doesn't address the main problem, it's an optimization tip.

Comment: not working! i have tried that too..but anyway the code works in chrome,ie but not in firefox

Comment: @user3222072 What jQuery version are you using? Can you create a [fiddle](http://http://jsfiddle.net/) to replicate your problems?

Comment: @user3222072 then it's should be fine with all browsers, can you create a basic fiddle, no need full code, just the relevant part so I can help you more :)